# Microphone driver in VM Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

I have installed pyttsx3 for my speech recognition project and even after successfully recording my audio terminal sends back a exception calling **init**.py.
With the help of SpeechRecognition I tried to build this program and it gives some error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/weakref.py", line 131, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
        speak_text(My_text)
      File "main.py", line 8, in speak_text
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
      File "/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
        eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
      File "/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
        self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
      File "/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
        self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 9, in <module>
        from . import _espeak, toUtf8, fromUtf8
      File "/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/_espeak.py", line 18, in <module>
        dll = cdll.LoadLibrary('libespeak.so.1')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 451, in LoadLibrary
        return self._dlltype(name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is the error but before that my program had executed fine.

Comment: it can't find `libespeak.so.1` - you may have to install `apt install espeak` or `apt install libespeak1`. Or maybe you will have to find it on disk and copy to folder `/home/cyclo97/trial/Translator/trans/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers`

Comment: on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) I have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libespeak.so.1.1.48` and link to this file as `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libespeak.so.1`